# List comprehension syntax error for appending word length to a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was trying to put the below example into a List Comprehension from NLP with Python, question 10 in chapter 3. I have tried all kinds of combinations to try to get this comprehension to work. I want to display the word in 'sent' next to the length of that word.

```
import nltk
sent =  sent = ['The', 'dog', 'gave', 'John', 'the', 'newspaper']
result = []

[word_len=(word, len(word)), result.append(word_len) for word in sent]
File "<stdin>", line 1
[word_len = (word, len(word)), result.append(word_len) for word in sent]
              ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Or [word_len=(word, len(word)) result.append(word_len) for word in sent]

Comment: Assignment is not part of a a list comprehension. What output did you expect to produce?

Comment: Your syntax is *way off* I am afraid. Perhaps you need to [re-read the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want :

```
[(word, len(word)) for word in sent]
```

Your question is not related to nltk though, it's just pure list comprehension.

Comment: I just edited away their ntlk tags and added list-comprehension

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do with the comprehension, just print the word, and the length of it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have assignment inside a list comprehension. You also shouldn't use it for side effects (e.g. your `result.append(word_len)`.

Either don't use a list comprehension here.

```
sent = ['The', 'dog', 'gave', 'John', 'the', 'newspaper']

result = []
some_list = []

for word in sent:
    result.append(len(word))
    some_list.append((word, len(word))
```

Or if all you're doing is populating result, just make that a list comprehension directly.

```
result = [len(word) for word in sent]
```

To expand on the "side effect" warning, you COULD do something like:

```
result = []

[result.append(len(word)) for word in sent]
```

This will populate `result` as you wanted, but is bad form. It creates a list of `None`s in memory (since `list.append` always returns `None`) that doesn't really need to exist.